# Alexa Intent Swithing context

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new to the Alexa Developing, i used ApiToBot third party application to create and build the intents and responses,
I used HTTPS method to contact the server.
Then i successfully deployed the project into the alexa developer account.
while i'm testing the application i stuck into the error.

Right now i have to Intent and their responses are from HTTPS server.
After opened the skill i received a welcome response, after that i called one intent i received response.

but i call second intent it is not showing the response and vise-versa.

Only one intent is working.

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue?. what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Simply saying . i had 4 intent and their responses in my alexa skill. when i test the skill by saying alexa open SKILL NAME. After that i ask one intent it is working perfectly and next i ask another intent it is giving default response from the alexa. conversation between alexa and user is not working.

Comment: Share the request and response JSON of each request.

Comment: I used APITOBOT third party application for api calls through https.please check it once http://apitobot.io/

Comment: everytime you interact with your skill a request will be generated, pls share that request and you response.

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/12xji4  this is the json file i have. kindly check it once

Comment: This is your interaction model. Share the JSON generated when you test it from the simulator.

Comment: this is the json generated when i tested in simulator. https://api.myjson.com/bins/kr76c

Comment: and what was your response JSON?

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/c65ek   this is response json

Comment: Thanks Cicil Thomas , Your answer solved all issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope [this](https://api.myjson.com/bins/kr76c) is your request and [this](https://api.myjson.com/bins/c65ek) was your response.

If that the case, your response has `shouldEndSession` parameter is set to `true`. What that means is that, once your response is read, Alexa will end the session and closes the skill. You are no longer inside the skill. Whenever you want Alexa to wait for user response, keep the session alive by setting `shouldEndSession` parameter set to `false`.

Ex: you response should be

```
{
  "body": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": "<speak><p>Followers of user id 641 is [Martijn Verbove Anton Cooee Found Ryze Rebekah Radice Jonah Lupton Mila Chervenkova David Morrison Tiep Vu Nicholas Tenhue Deepak Laxmi Narasimha Feda Jaan Lolly Daskal Hämorrhoiden selbst behandeln SF Ali Nicole Hardin Pradeep Chopra WhatUsersDo Alice Jones Arpit Maheshwari Мартин Стојчевски Pete Roome Dean Pikock.com Chad Scira Phil Hendrix] </p></speak>"
      },
      "shouldEndSession": false
    }
  }
}
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52113297/1574023) to know more about keeping the session alive using [ask-nodejs-sdk](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs)

More info about Response Object [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-object).