# Ask user for input from LaunchIntent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing a skill in Node JS 8. I have an intent set up with slots and it works properly if I say

> Ask {skill name} to {utterance}.

I'd like to design my skill so that the user can just say

> Open {skill Name}

and on opening it will ask them for input that will then be handled and passed to the intent. I've seen multiple people say that you can't do this. But I've used 2 skills today that did exactly this. I'm just looking for the correct syntax to do this.

I have:

```
'LaunchRequest': function() {
   this.response.speak("What note would you like?");
   this.emit(':responseReady');
}
```

Which seems like it should work, but I'm pretty new to JS and Alexa.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

When the skill user open your skill, you can give a welcome message followed by a question.
Ex:

```
[user]  : open note skill  
[Alexa] : Welcome to note skill. What note would you like?  
----------<Alexa will wait for users input>--------  
[user]  : ABC note.  
[Alexa] : <response>
```

In order for Alexa to wait for users input after it says the welcome message, you need to keep the session alive. The session is kept alive based on `shouldEndSession` parameter in the response. For any request, if not provided, `shouldEndSession` defaults to `true`. In your case, the response to `LaunchRequest` should have this `shouldEndSession` parameter set to `false`. Only by which the session remains open and users can continue interaction.

Ex:

```
'LaunchRequest': function() {
   const speech = "Welcome to note skill. What note would you like?";
   const reprompt = "What note would you like?";
   this.emit(':ask', speech, reprompt);
}
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51959848/1574023) to know more about how you can keep the session alive using ask-nodejs-sdk.

**Using Dialog Model**
Another way to achieve this is to use Dialog directives. Dialog directives helps you to fill and validate slot values easily. You can use the directives to ask the user for the information you need to fulfill their request.

More information on Dialog directives [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html)

Comment: Thanks so much, that's just what I needed.